# Is there a reason the Canon S90 is still more expensive than its successor the S95?

Tags: canon, digital, canon-s90

I've been dithering about getting an S90 for a year or more. Then of course the S95 came out and it looked as if this model came without the few and largely trivial things users objected to e.g. slippy control dial. However to my continued surprise, the S95 is much cheaper on the usual internet stores than its older brother. Is there a technical reason? I'd prefer to get myself the latest model, but this discrepancy is unsettling me, pre-purchase :-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. This is usually the case since stores do not reprice old cameras often enough. I've seen examples of far more ridiculous pricing.

Eventually when they realize the S90 is not selling, they will reduce the price. If they paid already more than it's worth, a store can probably get a manufacturer rebate to help sell stock without a loss. Different stores have different arrangements with the manufacturer, some manufacturer will take it back which is better for the store than to sell it at a loss, so there is no incentive to reduce the price. That also relieves pressure from the newer models.

Comment: Weird thing is, I was talking to a salesman at a leading UK photography outlet - he reckons the S90 is selling better across all their stores.  Said the same thing happened with Canon G10 and G11 too.

Comment: My guess is that could be a reputation effect. The S90 had time to be admired and praised by many (I highly recommend it to my photo students too) and the small step between the two models means that not so many people looked at the S95 (I did not even bother review it either, my time is better spend on more innovative models).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to look at the new price of an out-of-production item because it is priced for opaque reasons. The used market is perhaps a better indicator of how much an item is worth. On ebay the s90 is currently selling for 250-300, and the s95 is selling for 350-400. Of course this isn't a totally clean comparison because the s90s on ebay are probably more used than the s95s.